# Clion - executable is not specified

Tags: c, clion

im trying to run Clion on linux and im keep getting "executable is not specified" when im trying to run the code.

this is my CMakelist.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(123)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

set(SOURCE_FILES library.c library.h)
add_library(123 ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

i did not find a solution on the internet, someone have any idea what to do?

thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "run the code"? Execute CMake? Compile? Your project produces a library which cannot be executed as such.

Comment: there is a green play button (shift+F10) that build and execute the code.

Comment: Seems you need the executable with `main` function that is using your code from `lib123`. For example you can create the file `main.c` with the function `main` and use something from your `lib123` exports. CMakelist.txt  need to be change accordinly.